# Nginx not loading the second angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, nginx

Being new to Angular 4, Nodejs and Nginx i'm having trouble configuring Nginx to serve 2 different Angular apps. My problem is the following:

I generated two Angular 4 apps with the angular CLI and then modified them. Once done, I did a `ng build` on both of them to get the built files in the dist folder. The first app is the login page that does JWT Authentification with a backend in Nodejs. Once the auth is done it should redirect the user to the second app which is the actual website.
I use `window.location.href='http://localhost:8080/app'` in the login app to redirect to the second one.

Now since the second app is supposed to check the Token, it is stored in the browser's localStorage.
In order to keep this token, both the apps must be on the same address and port. Therefore I want to use NginX as a reverse proxy.

I installed Nginx and put the files of both apps in `/var/www/html/angular/login/` and `/var/www/html/angular/app/` respectively.

My Nginx `sites-available/default` file is the following:

```
#Default server configuration

server {
    listen 8080 default_server;
    #listen [::]:8080 default_server;

    index index.html;

    server_name localhost:8080/;

    location / {
        alias /var/www/html/angular/login/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /app {
        alias /var/www/html/angular/app;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```

Now what's happening is that when I go on `localhost:8080` I get my login app just as I should but when I authenticate, the url changes to `localhost:8080/app` as it should and the name of the app on the tab changes but the content of the app isn't loaded. It stays on the login page eventhough it seems to fetch the second app files...
It looks as if I had put the files of the login app in the `/var/www/html/angular/app/` folder eventhough I didn't.

Any idea where it comes from?

The apps were tested before using `ng serve` on 2 different ports but I couldn't keep the token since localStorage is attached to a domain and port.

Comment: what happens when you refresh?

Comment: The name of the Firefox tab changes from "Login App" to "Second App" and the url goes from `localhost:8080` to `localhost:8080/app/`. The content of the page however stays the same. I still have the login form and page and the input fields stay filled with the login and pass I typed.

Comment: Try changing `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;` in `/app` to `try_files $uri $uri/ =444;` and see if you get 444

Comment: I tried your code but I don't get 444 or any error in the console. The GETs seems to go through.

Comment: Remove the `location /` block and then test. See where it is going and why

Comment: Ok so now on `localhost:8080` I get the 'Welcome to nginx' page but weirdly enough when I go on `localhost:8080/app/` I still get the login page but with the title of the second app...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155427/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-karim).